# why systems like these don't work

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose there is a thermal reservoir at temp T1 which is more than temperature T2 of a piston cylinder system. So it can transfer heat to system. Then the system  gaining heat do work of friction on a body at temp T3 which is higher than that of reservoir.
How is this mechanism against  second law? And thus not possible? What stops it from functioning like this?
Edit:Device works in a cycle.

Comment: Can you make a sketch to clarify the system?

Comment: The correct answer to the question as stated is **NOT** "not possible". If that IS the correct answer then you have not stated the question correctly.

Comment: *"How is this mechanism against second law?"*...you do not cite any reason why this mechanism *should* be against the second law. It's *unclear what you're asking*.

Comment: Yes i think i got it. The device in question is possible if it isn't required to be cyclic and impossible if required to be cyclic as the second law says. Thankyou all.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, then:-

- Object 1 is a thermal mass at temperature T1.
- Object 2 is a piston (partially) filled with fluid, at temperature T2, where T2 < T1.  The piston is pressing against object 3. There's an implicit assumption that the meeting point between the piston rod and object 3 is a poor thermal conductor.
- Object 3 is sitting on a high-friction surface.  It is at temperature T3, where T3 > T1.

If we hold object 1 against object 2, then the fluid heats up and expands.  As the fluid expands, it pushes out the piston, pushing object 3 across the high-friction surface.  That causes object 3 to become even hotter.

If that's the case, then the answers would be:

- It isn't.
- It is possible.
- Nothing.

Comment: Yes it is the exact question statement and correct answer is :not possible. What is the reason behind?

Comment: I have no idea.  There may be some other condition that you haven't stated.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe can be achieved and breaks no laws of physics (which is the same thing put differently :-) ).

What cannot be achieved is to end up with more energy at the end of the process than you had at the start.

Consider this as a "heat engine" problem. 
Assume that all temperatures are absolute temperatures (eg say degrees K).

### Requirement:

A heat engine has inlet or source temperature $T_1$ and (lower temperature) outlet or sink temperature $T_2$. The heat engine does work on a volume of fluid* at temperature $T_3$ (where $T_3\gt T_1$) raising the fluid temperature to $T_4$ (where $T_4 \gt T_3$), i.e. $T_4\gt T_3 \gt T_1 \gt T_2$.

*<sup>The heating process can be achieved with friction but is usually better understood in terms of gas compression if measurement of heat transfer etc is desired. (e.g. if friction is used - what does it heat, what is the energy transferred (mass, temperature, specific heat, ...) and how do you measure it.</sup>

### Result

The maximum possible theoretical efficiency of the heat engine is achieved by a Carnot cycle process with maximum possible efficiency $Z_{max}$ of
$$\begin{align}Z_{max} &= \frac{T_{hot}-T_{cold}}{T_{hot}}\\  
&=\frac{T_1-T_2}{T_1}\end{align}$$

If the process of raising the temperature of fluid from $T_3$ to $T_4$ was also carried out with a Carnot cycle the maximum efficiency achievable would again be
$$\begin{align}Z_{max} &= \frac{T_h-T_c}{T_h} \\  
&= \frac{T_4-T_3}{T_4}\end{align}$$ 
[Somewhere about here the question of COP for a heat pump becomes relevant. COP can be >1 and increases as $\Delta T ( = T_h-T_c)$ becomes small compared with $T_h$, but the above relationship still cannot be violated.]

As long as these relationships were not broken then the process is conceptually possible.
In practice achievable efficiencies are substantially below the theoretical Carnot limit. Achieving better than 50% of Carnot efficiency is usually doing well and usually involves high temperatures, high pressures and high specific heat gases (typically Hydrogen or Helium).